# How to Get Directory and filename from User for vaadin download

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

.hi. 
I am trying to download a file from vaadin server. i found [FileDownloader](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Letting+the+user+download+a+file/exclusive)`FileDownloader(StreamResource resource , String fileName)` that i can use for my purpose. But I'm looking for a way to get the directory and filename from client graphically and set it to my StreamResource. Something like a file chooser...
what component can I use? 
I'm new to everything! so if my question is obscure, let me know(give me comment).

Comment: This is Not passable. You can ask the User via a TextField for the Name, but the Directory where the file is saved is outside of servercontrol. This is Not a vaadin restriction, It 's that way for all weebsolutions

Comment: If it's the server you want to _browse_ for certain files, you could start from a _root_ directory, [walk through all its children](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) and populate a Tree or TreeGrid to visually display something similar to windows explorer (you can also use icons to differentiate between folders and files). Then you could add a context menu to allow the user to download the selected file.

Comment: Or do you want to upload a file from client (where the browser runs on) to the server (where your Vaadin app runs on)? In that case you should check out the [upload component](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-upload.html).

Comment: no, i don't want to upload from client to server. i want to  download  a file from server and put that file in a specified directory in client system(Desktop for example) @SteffenHarbich

Comment: Then you should see @Morfic suggestion, that's a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As André pointed out in the comments, you cannot control where a downloaded file is stored by the browser on client system. Usually the browser will ask the user for a file location to save the file being downloaded.